dropdown in bootstrap menu displays stacked on an input box, instead of next to it
I'm adapting a web program using boostrap v. 5.2.3. There is an input box at the right edge of the page, and I want to add a dropdown menu next to it on the left. I used this code:
<div class="col-1 pe-3">
   <select name="display_format" id="display_format" class="col-1 form-control form-control-sm">
      <option value="display">Display</option>
      <option value="output">Output</option>
   </select>
   <input id="select_year" type="number" class="col-2 form-control form-control-sm">
</div>

If kind of worked, but the dropdown is displayed stacked on the input box, instead of before it, ideally with some kind of space inbetween.
Could someone please nudge me in the right direction?
I tried to look at bootstrap documentation, but it's very extensive, and I wasn't able to find, what does pe-3 mean...
Thanks for any help!

The p is for padding, the e is for end and 3 is the size.
In short: "3 padding" on the right side.
Sizing documentation
You can use an input group with a dropdown menu:
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect03" aria-label="Example select with button addon">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>

Or a flexbox with a select, as in your example, using these classes in the container element: d-flex flex-row flex flex-nowrap.
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex flex-nowrap" style="gap: 15px;">
   <select name="display_format" id="display_format" class="col-1 form-control form-control-sm">
      <option value="display">Display</option>
      <option value="output">Output</option>
   </select>
   <input id="select_year" type="number" class="col-2 form-control form-control-sm">
</div>

flex-nowrap prevents line breaks and forces elements to be next to each other. gap defines the spacing between elements inside the flexbox.

Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried it and it shows the dropdown next to the input window, but now the input window is out of the frame, too far right. What can I do to get it back?

You can reduce the width of the container or input using style='width: 100px;'
